# How to create a table with fixed layout?

Tags: html, css

Hai ,

I am using a html table for my website layout . 
when we press enter in one cell , the cell is resizing.
I used css for fixing the table layout. table layout is not changing .But cell is resizing.

```
.pageContent table
{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    table-layout:fixed;
}
.pageContent table tr td
{
  padding:5px 10px 5px 10px;
 }
```

how to prevent this resizing of table cells ?

Comment: At which point are you pressing `enter` exactly?

Comment: try not using tables for page layout. Use semantic html whenever possible. DIVS are perfect for layout. With this said, please post your page somewhere where we can see it because it will be easier to understand your question with a live example.

Comment: @pixeline - there is nothing in this question to suggest the table is being used for layout. It could be a report table, for example, in which case DIVs might well be the worse choice.

Comment: @Tom: "am using a html table for my website layout "

Comment: @pixeline... uhh, I must have been blind to that line. My apologies. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table is re-sizing because you are using proportional widths.

There are many ways you can control this. For example, by setting your  or  height in pixels:

```
CSS:
table td {height: 20px;}
```

Your cells will no longer re-size vertically.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding the following CSS

```
td { overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap;  }
tr { height:1em;  } /* or set an appropriate height and width */
```

This will hide the overflow in the cells however, but they won't resize.

Your layout might be easier to do with semantically correct HTML, using `<div>` elements but would need to see the markup.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to be sure, but you haven't set a size on the td in question, only padding. So the td will be expanding to contain whatever is inside it. In some browsers this might change a wee bit with focus.

Could you try setting an explicit width and height (in ems or pixels) for the td?

```
.pageContent table tr td
{
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  width:8em;
  height:2em;
}
```

Could you post a bit of your markup, or let us know what the content in the cells is? (And which browsers you're seeing the problem in).